# How can I make this action in react work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

When I replace "this.props.fetchInfo(recipe.id)" with console.log(recipe.id), the "recipe.id" is logged when the div is clicked. However, the action is never fired. I have another console.log in my actual action creator that would log the id if it is actually passed in, but I just get an error (which I expect, but I figure I would at least get the id logged before the errors in my console). I'm not sure if the structure is set up correctly for the "Recipe" component although it appears as it is. Also, I'm not sure if there is a more correct way to do what I'm trying to do, which is to take in a piece (recipe.id) of the state from my last AJAX request and use it to make a second AJAX request to return the info I need. The following is the Recipe component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchInfo } from "../actions";

// Here we take in the passed in props from the FoodList component and render
// the dishes for the inputted ingredients
class Recipe extends Component {
  renderFood(food) {
    return (
      <div className="food-container">
        {food.map(function(recipe) {
          console.log(recipe.id);
          return (
            <div
              className="indiv-recipe"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: "url(" + recipe.image + ")"
              }}
              onClick={() => this.props.fetchInfo(recipe.id)}
            >
              <div id="recipe-title"> {recipe.title}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.foods.map(this.renderFood)}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchInfo }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Recipe);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I coded something I believe you are trying to do.

```js
class Recipe extends React.Component {

  renderFood(foods) {
    
    return (
      <div>
        {foods.map(recipe => (
            <div
              key={recipe.id}
              onClick={() => this.props.fetchInfo(recipe.id)}
            >
              <div id="recipe-title">{recipe.title}</div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { foods } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderFood(foods)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const foodsList = [
 { title: "beans", id: 1 },
 { title: "rice", id: 2 },
];

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = { received: false, info: null };
  
  fetchInfo(id) {
    this.setState({
      received: true,
      info: id,
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { received, info } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
       {received && (<div>{info}</div>)}
        <Recipe
          foods={foodsList}
          fetchInfo={(id) => this.fetchInfo(id)}
        />
      </div>
    );
 };
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

You are binding in the wrong way.

Replace

`{food.map(function(recipe) {`

with

`{food.map(recipe => {`

Comment: Nothing changed, it just made my code look nicer but thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate it, I'm going to go through it now.